# Баг в меню навигации wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Работаю над сайтом `http://secinteg.com/`, он на wordpress, тема Avada. Столкнулся со странным багом в меню навигации, при прокручивании страницы вниз быстро переключаются якорные ссылки с активной на главную. Баг есть в firefox и ie, в chrome через раз. Как это починить?

Comment: Не знаю всех ваших javascript но эта проблема с ними рыть надо туда. Возможно в плагине переключения меню

Comment: В общем исходя из того что я посмотрел по скриптам вы не правильно указали селекторы для изменения меню в настройках темы. поэтому так и происходит.

Comment: @sergalas спасибо за ответ. Я не изменял скрипты, только задавал id для якорей в настройках темы. На селекторы вешаются только стили. Вы можете подробнее объяснить, где ошибка?

Comment: я понимаю что вы не меняли скрипт вы указали id не того селектора ну к примеру
<body>
    <div id="one">
         <div></div>
     </div>

Comment: <body>
    <div id="one">
         <div></div>
     </div>
    <div id="two">
         <div id="three"></div>
     </div>
Скорее всего вы указали срабатывания скрипта по div с id tree